# Magento and salesforce integration to create opportunity as closed won inside salesfore once order become complete in magento store

Tags: soap, curl, salesforce, magento

I had implemented a salesforce integration with magento orders. To achieve this , i had followed the steps given below. I am doing something wrong in 4th step while inserting salesforce_company_id and salesforce_contact_id in user account.

**1)Add custom option 'closed' in admin to make any order complete.**

```
public function massCompleteAction(){
$orderIds = $this->getRequest()->getPost('order_ids', array());
$countCompleteOrder = 0;
foreach ($orderIds as $orderId) {
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
if ($order->canComplete()) {
$order->complete()->save();
$countCompleteOrder++;
}
}
if ($countCompleteOrder>0) {
$this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('%s order(s) successfully put on complete', $countCompleteOrder));
}else {
// selected orders is not available for hold
}
$this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

**2)Add two additional fields for user account, Salesforce Company and Salesforce Contact.**

I had followed following link http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/customer-registration-fields-magento1-6

**3)Create a custom reseller registration form that will create a simple user in magento**

```
public function createResellerAction()
{

$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
  $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
  $password = $params["password"];
  $email = $params["email"];
  $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
  $customer->loadByEmail($email);
 //Zend_Debug::dump($customer->debug()); exit;
if(!$customer->getId()) {
$customer->setEmail($email);
$customer->setFirstname($params["firstname"]);
$customer->setLastname($params["lastname"]);
$customer->setPassword($password);

 try {
$customer->save();
$customer->setConfirmation(null);
$customer->save();
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customer->getId());
   }
   catch (Exception $ex) {
//Zend_Debug::dump($ex->getMessage());
}

$_custom_address = array (
'firstname' => $params["firstname"],
'lastname' => $params["lastname"],
'street' => array (
    '0' => $params["add1"],
    '1' => $params["add2"],
),

'city' => $params["city"],
'region_id' => '',
'region' => '',
'postcode' => $params["zipcode"],
'country_id' => '', /* Croatia */
'telephone' => $params["phone"],
);

$customAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
$customAddress->setData($_custom_address)
        ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
        ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
        ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
        ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');

    try {
$customAddress->save();
        }
    catch (Exception $ex) {
//Zend_Debug::dump($ex->getMessage());
    }
```

**4) Create company and contact in salesforce during reseller action**

```
$sObject1 = new stdclass();
            $sObject1->Name = $params["company"];    
            $createResponse1 = $mySforceConnection->create(array($sObject1), 'Account');
            foreach ($createResponse1 as $createResult1) {
                $compid = $createResult1->id;
                 }

            $sObject3 = new stdclass();
            $sObject3->FirstName = $params["firstname"];
            $sObject3->LastName = $params["lastname"];
            $sObject3->Email = $params["email"];
            $sObject3->AccountId = $compid;  
            $createResponse2 = $mySforceConnection->create(array($sObject3), 'Contact');
            foreach ($createResponse2 as $createResult2) {
                $contid = $createResult2->id;
                 }
             $saledata = array (
            'salesforce_company_id' => $compid,
             'salesforce_contact_id' => $contid,
             );
             $customersale = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
            $customersale->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
  $customersale->loadByEmail($email);
 //Zend_Debug::dump($customer->debug()); exit;
if($customersale->getId()) {
              $customersale->setData($saledata);
                   try {
                    $customersale->save();
                     $customersale->setConfirmation(null);
                     $customersale->save();
                  }
                catch (Exception $ex) {
                 $message = $this->__($customer);
                //Zend_Debug::dump($ex->getMessage());
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($message);
                }
            }
```

**Please check the code where i am wrong at the bottem of 4th step**

```
$saledata = array (
            'salesforce_company_id' => $compid,
             'salesforce_contact_id' => $contid,
             );
             $customersale = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
            $customersale->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
  $customersale->loadByEmail($email);
 //Zend_Debug::dump($customer->debug()); exit;
if($customersale->getId()) {
              $customersale->setData($saledata);
                   try {
                    $customersale->save();
                     $customersale->setConfirmation(null);
                     $customersale->save();
                  }
                catch (Exception $ex) {
                 $message = $this->__($customer);
                //Zend_Debug::dump($ex->getMessage());
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($message);
                }
            }
```

I await your responses.

Comment: Calling `setData()` on the customer overwrites the data that existed in that model.  Try using `addData()`.

Comment: Thanks @nick, i have found solution.    $customer->setSalesforce_company_id($compid);
      $customer->setSalesforce_contact_id($contid);
           try {
        $customer->save();
         }
        catch (Exception $ex1) {
         //Zend_Debug::dump($ex->getMessage());
        }

Comment: Yeah, that's right.  If you use `->setData($key, $value)` instead of `->setData(array())` you only replace the one item in the data store, not the entire thing.  Using `->addData()` would have done what you wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a great extension for magento which does that all for you and even more: https://products.crunchyconsulting.com/crunchy-products/crunchy-magforce.html

Take a look at help & docs tab where you can find even movies with use case scenarios

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TjxvjGcAGqY

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cmf4Ksv3uRM